# Graphviz not drawing border around subgraph

Tags: border, graphviz, subgraph

Consider the following Graphviz code:

```
digraph g1 { 
    compound = true;
    node [shape = box, style=filled, fillcolor=Khaki] a;

    subgraph sg1 {
        node [shape = "", style="", fillcolor=""] b -> c;
        graph [style=solid, penwidth=3];
    }
}
```

this yields:

[image]

Why am I not getting a border around the subgraph/cluster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sg1 must be a cluster to have the border drawn

ie. rename it to eg. cluster_sg1

[edit]

Or Add line: cluster=true inside subgraph
see documentation here: https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/cluster/

Comment: You mean, keep the subgraph command but rename it from `sg1` to `cluster_sg1`? How bizarre! ... but it works. Is there a way to make something a cluster without its name starting with `cluster_`, or is this my only option?

Comment: there is no way arround starting cluster but things like "cluster sg1" and clusterSg1 will also work

Comment: `cluster sg1` doesn't work - it gives me another box named "cluster" in addition to "sg1"...

Comment: you must include the qoutes in that case

Comment: Quotes around what?

Comment: "cluster sg1" or any ID that contains space, or in other ways is not a c-identifier nor a floating point value. The syntax is explained here:https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html

Comment: You can also add the "cluster=true" attribute to the subgraph:

Comment: @UdoEisenbarth thanks  for pointing that out wasn't aware of the cluster attribute